# Unable to restart windows service from my ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am trying to restart Windows Time Service from my asp.net application using the following code but it always return s a TimeoutException. I have tried various ways to remove this error and restart the service but unfortunately fails in it. The code which i am using for this purpose is shown below:

```
private ServiceController service = 
     new ServiceController( "W32Time", Environment.MachineName );
private TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 35000 );//15000 was the old value

// Restart W32Time Service
private void RestartService( )
{
    try
    {
        // Stop service if it is running
        if( service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running )
        {
            service.Stop( );
            service.WaitForStatus( ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout );
        }

        // Start service if it is stopped
        if( service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped )
        {
            if (!(service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) || 
                  service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))
            {
                service.Stop();
            }

            service.Start( );
            service.WaitForStatus( ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout );
        }
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        log.Error( "Error in restarting windows service.", ex );
    }
}
```

I am using Windows 7. Can anyone suggest me a solution for this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works just fine for me with the VS built-in web server.

Which leads me think that the user which your web app run under does not have permission to start/stop services. This would either be the AppPool user or your logged in user depending on how the app is configured.

Comment: Might be an UAC issue, and I assume your user is running as admin. If you start VS as admin, will it work then?

Comment: Not it is not working with admin rights i.e. when i start VS with admin and then run the web app from that VS